How do speakers of gendered languages experience English [non-gendered] nouns?
In many languages nouns have a gender assigned (masculine, feminine, or neuter) which affects the nouns themselves and changes the forms of related words like adjectives and verbs. In English, most nouns don’t have gender, except for a few cases like "waiter/waitress" or "actor/actress" (but I think those are used less and less, in current times)
I am curious how speakers of languages with gendered nouns see English nouns. For example, when a Spanish speaker sees the English word "teacher," does the absence of any gender marking create any confusion, or does translating become tricky since gendered languages need to change words to keep everything grammatically correct?
If a person's first language has gendered nouns, how does that affect their learning of English nouns? Does it make it easier or harder to understand and use them?

My experience is that the nouns present little difficulty, but pronouns are often confused, using he or she where it is appropriate, for example.

@LPH It's more useful to compare "actor" and "actress". They've both increased, but "actor" has increased much more. So it seems like we're taliking about the profession more in general, but using the generic term more in proportion.

As a non-native speaker with German mother tongue, I don't remember even noticing. You'll need to learn many new things about grammar, spelling, and pronunciation when you learn your first foreign language, the lack of gender is just one "oddity" out of many, and hardly the most confusing one. Frankly, I remember half of my early English classes as "memorising how stuff is pronounced and spelled" - the utter lack of consistency in this regard is what is really noticeable and confusing.

@xLeitix: Yeah the sound and spell thing does suck. There's only a few hundred special cases and the rest do in fact follow regular rules but it turns out you have to know the word's meaning to know how to resolve apparent conflicts in the rules. So if you encounter an unknown word, knowing it's a noun or a verb or an adjective doesn't really help enough.

We don't care.
It is one less thing to worry about when learning English.
But if you were an English native speaker trying to learn agendered language…you are going to have a lots of fun. And by "fun" I mean frustrated screaming.
It is easy to ignore the gender of nouns, but it is mind-boggling to learn a new dimension that your language does not have concept of. English tenses still confuse me to this day - my language only has 3 (past, present, future), not twelve.

"We do not care!" :D Straight and to the point, thank you! I agree that the challenge is probably so much greater the other way. Half of my family lives in Iceland, and from what I understand about the language, you not only have to consider gender, but also nouns, pronouns, and adjectives change form based on their role in a sentence. Terrifying!

Which language solely utilizes 3?

@RokeJulianLockhart  Hebrew, for one, has only past, present and future tenses

If you speak to me in three tenses I will surely understand you.

@RokeJulianLockhart: Esperanto uses past, present and future tenses, although with 6 modes. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esperanto_grammar#The_verbal_paradigm

@Joshua We understand it, but they sound weird and it marks them as foreigners. Similar to Russians leaving out articles.

As bad as gendered nouns are. Transitioning from a language with ungendered pronouns to gendered pronouns is worse.

@RokeJulianLockhart Persian, for example, basically just uses 3 tenses, although they have more.

I would just like to add that learning a gendered language as a speaker of a different gendered language might suck even more. For me, learning German was no fun at all given that German genders for many words don't match the genders in my native language (Czech). For example, "city" is feminine in German, but neuter in Czech.


If a person's first language has gendered nouns, how does that affect their learning of English nouns? Does it make it easier or harder to understand and use them?

Simpler forms are usually easier to use - in this sense English poses less challenges than, e.g., learning another gendered language, where the genders of many nouns are different from the native one. This is especially true, if the gender is not easily inferred grammatically (like in German or French, and unlike in Italian.)
One however can often recognize speakers of gendered languages by their using he/she where English uses it. Although grammatically incorrect, this usually poses little impediment to communication, as compared to other features of English - like its system of tenses, idiosyncratic use of phrasal verbs and prepositions, etc.

That's interesting that its more of a small "marker" for someone still learning the language. For English speakers learning a new language, it could be similar to how they might misuse verb tenses or struggle with phrasal verb placement.

Another common "marker" I've noticed is using possessive pronouns that agree with the object. So when talking about my wife's family, a learner might say "her aunt" vs "his uncle" when it should actually be "her" for both cases.

@CharlieB it depends on their native language - in some languages possessives agree with the possessor (like in English, Russian), in others with the possessed (e.g., French, Italian, though a male possessive may be used before a vowel), and sometimes with both (German.)

As a native speaker of Catalan (a romance gendered language) having studied English (non gendered) and some German (gendered), I can confirm that the gender issue is easier for me in English than in German. Not having genders is easy, but there are words where genders don't make sense neither in German nor in Catalan, and guessing the German gender is not straightforward. In fact, German has words where genders could make a lot of sense but don't (like Mädchen).

@Pere It doesn't make sense that Mädchen is neuter gender, but at least it's predictable: all diminutives in German are neuter.

@AndyB In that case it makes a good sense, no? BTW, these diminutives are neuter in Slavic languages as well. Whíle dívka and holka are feminine (all meaning a girl), děvče is neuter, precisely because it is a diminutive.

@VladimirFГероямслава some German words have clear gender markers, like "-chen" suffix, but there is no general way to distinguish the gender. Same in French: -ette, -esse, -ée mark feminine, -ment is always masculine, but there's no general rule - e.g. "chose" and "maison" are both feminine. Besides, it is counterintuitive when a word has gender different from the one's native language, even if clearly marker - e.g., I have a difficulty with spiders - "araignée" (fem)

(as a native Spanish speaker, I will write about Spanish; I'm not sure if what I say applies to all languages with gendered nouns)
The question seems based on the pre-conceived notion that gendered-nouns are perceived by the speaker as gendered as objects. And for the vast majority of cases, this is not true at all. In fact basically the opposite is true, where English speakers seems to consistently assign gender to certain objects (ships, cars, planes) while Spanish speakers would not do so.
To try to exemplify how it (does not) work for a Spanish speaker:

aircraft (=aeronave) is feminine, while plane (=avión) is masculine

embarcación (=boat) is feminine, while barco (=boat) is masculine

pantalla (=screen) is feminine, while monitor (=monitor) is masculine

cuchilla (=bigknife) is feminine, while cuchillo (=knife) is masculine

cerca (=fence) is feminine, while cerco (=fence) is masculine

espada (=sword) is feminine, while sable (=saber) is masculine

pistola (=pistol) is feminine, while revolver (=revolver) is masculine

bigote (=moustache) is masculine, while barba (=beard) is feminine

in Argentina, violent groups of males will use feminine nouns to describe themselves (barra, patota).


And it goes on and on. I struggle to find examples where the gender of the noun does affect how it is perceived.

The closest example to arbitrary genders affecting the perception of an object that I can find are folk tales of the Sun marrying the Moon. Translating those tales from Catalan (or Spanish) to German would reverse genders. Or if you translate "Un toro enamorado de la Luna" to German you can get a nice romantic song about a gay bull - nice but quite different from its original intention.

Good example. But that's very specific of a poetic view. In Spanish one says "el sol es una estrella" (the sun---masculine---is a star---feminine). And one also says "la luna es un cuerpo celeste" (the moon---feminine---is a celestial body---masculine).

"English speakers seems to consistently assign gender to certain objects (ships, cars, planes)." As mentioned in my comment on another answer, a plane or a ship is idiomatically "it" for anyone but sailors and those trying to imitate them, particularly a plane—even a gate attendant at the airport is very unlikely to say "she has arrived" when talking about a plane. And cars most of all—I think only a person who blatantly personified a car would call it "she."

And there is certainly something to be said about sexism in personification in general, which can go far beyond vehicles: I suspect that someone would be much more likely to say "she's pretty impressive, isn't she?" than "he's very impressive, isn't he?" when talking about a house, a car, a machine.... But personification of an animal, which is much more common, will often default to "he." Certainly much to consider about ownership and agency and how they tie into gender roles. But the first kind of personification is rare in any case. Most people just would use "it."

In French, "masculine fashion" is said "la mode masculine", where "fashion = la mode" is a feminine noun. I have always found that apparently contradictory wordplay particularly delicious.

@DenisG.Labrecque: indeed. That made me notice that in Spanish beard ("barba") is feminine.

@MartinArgerami same in French; beard, mustache, testicles -- all have feminine articles. Noun "gender" is truly meaningless: therefore, native speakers do not notice their lack in English, as all they are is rote memorization.

@MartinArgerami Thank you for your insights! My question was about understanding how speakers of languages with gendered nouns perceive and navigate the absence of gender marking in English, and whether this lack of gender affects comprehension and translation of nouns. So not necessarily implying that gendered nouns influence how objects are perceived. Still your insights on how grammatical gender does not always equate to gendered perceptions, are another layer of complexity I had no realized, so I appreciate what you've shared!

@emmabee: thanks for your comment :) With my answer I was trying to emphasize the point, already mentioned in other answers, that the lack of gender in English nouns is entirely irrelevant for a Spanish speaker; for the gender is a property of the word and not of the object the word designates.

Rational beings might have come to the conclusion that the arbitrary assignment of gender to things is an aberration in modern languages, and I am one of them. I take as a basis for my observation my mother tongue, French, in which arbitrary genders are assigned to nouns for common things, as in Latin, and for which the authorities have very recently allowed the general use of feminine forms for the names of functions, the words that name the various occupations a person may have. Of course, the diversity that gender adds to the set of nouns and the consequent modifications on the other words in the sentence can provide an additional easy means of identification of terms in the sentence, but this is a principle that is of no help in a good number of circumstances and you have then to rely on other devices; anyway it is not available until you have assimilated a rather voluminous grammatical paraphernalia that goes along with this principle of assignment of genders. One might wonder in the end what is a real advantage of an arbitrary attibution of genders.
When it comes to words for functions, this principle still results in aberration, as two terms are used in parallel for what is but one single function; to compound this illogicality, when a group of persons (of both sexes) having the same function has to be identified by the name of their function—that happens often—there is no term to do so; logically, a third, plural, mixed gender term should be used, but there is none—the use of three terms for a single function seems a very impractical way to deal with this question, and of course, no one even suggests anything such as that, as they are too aware of what is implied—; you are in fact left to your own devices in this case, and you are inclined to use the plural for the masculine term, as in the past, which results in incoherence; the option of using  a coordination of the two "functions"  is of course a heavy burden ("les professeurs et les professeures"), which at times is not even a possibility: for instance the feminine for  "vétérinaire" (veterinarian) cannot be derived by using an inflection, and there is a certain number of  words for naming functions that are like that.
Anyone willing to face the facts is bound to recognize the superiority of English in that domain, and on all counts: preservation of a  perfect logic, simplicity where no complication is needed, ease and rapidity in the learning process, ease and rapidity in the use of the language, less errors when using it, keeping at a minimum a useless clutter in the mind, thus freeing it for more productive thinking tasks. So foreign speakers of English who think as I do see the English system of providing nouns to things as, in itself and as far as we restrict ourselves to the present considerations, an irreproachable system. In fact if nothing else has opened somone's eyes to these realities in their own  language (characterized by arbitrary genders and/or gender-marked), the learning of English should more or less rapidly do so, and they couldn't conceivably fuel a possible  stance of detractor of English on the basis of this particular characteristic.
Of course, the difficulty in a translation to English is negligible in comparison to that of translating idioms and cultural references; you can go about it in a routine-like manner, even more so as there is a simplification in the rendering; a set of straightforward grammatical rules is all that is needed. Translation from English is nothing but a problem inherent to the foreign language, and it will be more or less easily solved according to how systematic the language is. In French, for instance, a certain care will be needed in deciding which gender to use, in finding a feminine counterpart for a genderless English word for a function, and in finding which term or expression will do for a mixed gender plural.
A person coming to English from a language where gender is extensively used for nouns is not affected at all as a learner. The learner simply distanciates him/herself from his/her native language and takes to the simple "noun system" of English; why find difficulty where things are kept as simple as they should be?. That is at least how I see this question from my point of view of French student of English. I might add that, personally, my adhesion to this system is such that I am most reluctant at the idea of conforming to the restricted Anglo-saxon usage that consists in conferring to things like ships, engines, car, cats, etc a feminine gender, that being so in the light of the fact that the word "car" is feminine in French.

Unlike ships, engines, cars etc., cats do come in gendered varieties!

Most English speakers who are not sailors or military are wont to refer to vehicles as "it," even ships. I sometimes see "she" used to refer to ships in publications that stubbornly imitate a somewhat anachronistic nautical style, such as many Wikipedia pages, and that's about the only place.

To be clear, the use of "she" to refer to ships in certain people's English is sexist in a way that it arguably is not in French or other languages with gendered nouns, because it is not a remnant of arbitrary grammatical noun gender (e.g. scip is neuter in Old English), but is fundamentally an unconscious legacy of gender stereotypes vis-à-vis the "possession" of something by presumed heterosexual male sailors.

Also, in my gendered language, we will not use the equivalent of "she" just because the word for a "ship" is feminine (which it is) if the name of the ship is actually masculine. So the Ajax or Hood will always be masculine for us (a "he"), even if the word for a ship is feminine. Similarly for ships like Titanic where it may be harder to see why the names are perceived masculine. It is quite different from this English nautical practice.

@psmears: Stupid debate in spanish. Me: es la gato o es la gata? Other: es el gato. Me (not having the right vocabulary): No es. Es gato feminine.

@Joshua: Interestingly Google Translate gives "gata" as the primary translation for "cat"...

@Obie2.0: I remember when we had to care whether the computer was male or female. Now all computers are it. The part that mattered is long obsolete.

@Joshua - Given time, it may come full circle.
